# Swagger request body is generated incorrectly

Tags: java, swagger-ui

I'm currently working on generating API documentation using Swagger for my Java Spring Boot project. However, I'm encountering an issue where the request body fields are mapped to a different DTO (Data Transfer Object) class than expected.

The correct DTO for the request body is `ADTO.Request.Create`, but Swagger is incorrectly referring to `BDTO.Request.Create`. I want to keep the original class names and fix this problem by adjusting my Swagger configuration. Currently, I am using `swagger-ui-react v4.16.1` and I don't have any specific configuration.

Here are my DTO classes:

```java
public interface ADTO {
    public interface Request {
        public class Create {
            private Long id;
            private String name;
            private String telephone;
            private String mobile;
        }
    }
}
```

```java
public interface BDTO {
    public interface Request {
        public class Create {
            private Long id;
            private Long companyId;
            private Long userId;
            private Long contractLength;       
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!

Comment: I've edited my question. Can you have a look again @AztecCodes